# Displaying forms SelectField 'options'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

How to display selectField options in html, and toggle the options when clicked.

so basically remove the selectField drop down bar and just display all the options out.

```
    {% for x in form_select.select %}
        <option value="{{ x }}"> </option>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You need to add <select> tag, not only <options>

Comment: what do you mean by "toggle the options when clicked" ?
you mean : "change the value when we click on a select's option ? In this case don't worry it's a native behaviour. no need to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It's true sometime it's not very intuitive.

#### How to do it

So to **display select field in a django template**, just **do as follow** :

```
<select id="id_yourSelect" name="yourSelect">
{% for value, label in yourForm.fields.yourSelect.choices %}
    <option value="{{ value }}"{% if yourForm.fields.yourSelect.value == value %} selected{% endif %}>{{ label  }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

#### Explanation

1. First, we parse the selectfield's choices of yourForm. So we have
   the value and the label at each loop.
2. Don't forgot to compare the value of the select with the value of
   the current choice to make it selected. ;)

And you've got what you want if your form.py is correctly built whith choices.